# Mysql - How can I select column where row is in array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, phpmyadmin

I have a list of events in MySQL where there's event titles, event time, date etc. In each event there are invitees (people who got invited to the event).

So basically my table events table looks like this:

[image]

By looking at the table you'll notice that my `event_invitees` is an array, I managed to save an array using a tutorial [here](http://99webtools.com/blog/how-to-store-array-in-mysql/). So from this tutorial I am able to get the array out out the table.

What I want to so is `SELECT` a column form the table `WHERE` myString is in the `event_invitees` array

So using the image above as an example. I have a string "tnylee" I want to be able to select every row that contains the `event_invitees` called tnylee.

How can I do this? Is this possible?
Please comment if the question isn't clear enough

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you want to select based on the items inside the serialized string? oh no

Comment: @Ghost YES. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like keyword for filter the data

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE event_invitees LIKE '%tnylee%'
```

then you will receive results the column value as "tnylee" pattern.

You can check if the selected row contains exact value when you extract data(Using programme).

Comment: You can check the retrived data exact match with the result by programme

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing event_invitees in one serialized column better solution is to keep them in dependend table

this table will containt:

```
CREATE TABLE `CREATE TABLE `table_code` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_person` integer NOT NULL,
  `id_event` integer  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Anyway You can use 'LIKE' operator:
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE event_invitees LIKE '%YourSearch%'